# What does Trap the Soul do?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I see the 8th level wizard spell Trap the Soul in the PHB's spell lists on page 211, but it's not in the spell definitions. How does Trap the Soul work in 5E?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part confuses you?

Comment: Quote the 5E spell definition and where you found it.

Comment: As written, this question is not a good fit for RPG.SE. Before posting a question, we ask that you do a reasonable effort of research to answer the question yourself. For this reason, "read the rules to me" questions are considered off-topic on this site. If you have a specific question about using _Trap the Soul_ in a specific context, please edit your question with those details and we will be happy to address it.

Comment: I did research it and found it on the spell listing for wizard in the PHB 211 but not in the spell definitions following the listings.

Comment: Hence me asking for how it works and the wording of the spell.

Comment: If you had tried to answer my question before accusing me of not doing research, you'd have seen that.

Comment: It would be helpful of you to clarify that you are asking these questions _because_ they do not seem to appear in the published material. We _do_ get questions that are just asking us to quote material. In general it is good practice to provide context to your questions, especially when they can be easily interpreted as invalid.

Comment: Point taken. I'll bear that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Trap the Soul spell for D&D 5e (yet). It was either deliberately dropped from the book during production or accidentally cut out during editing, but left in the PHB lists.

Comment: So not just a misprint in my book. Gotcha